# Retrieve multiple rows from sqlite using where clause Android

Tags: android, sqlite

When I try to retrieve multiple rows from SQLite by using the WHERE clause, I am getting only the first row... i.e.: `mCursor.getCount()` returns 1 always...
Is there any way to retrieve multiple rows from a table by using the WHERE clause?
This is what i have tried so far[image: ScreenShot]

```
myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    String query= "SELECT * FROM location where emirate='"+s+"'";
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    int i= mCursor.getCount();
    if (i>0) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
           shoplist.add(mCursor.getString(1));
        }
        mCursor.close();
        myDataBase.close();
    }
```

Comment: have you logged the value of mCursor.getCount()?

Comment: I have tried to view it using breakpoints... and it returns 1 always...

Comment: **Of course** you don't get all the records listed. You **aren't cycling** through the results. You are also getting the **2nd** column, not the first one (they are **0 based**). And you have no warranty of **which** will be the second column the next time you'll execute the query, since **columns don't came in a specific order**.

Comment: You are not iterating through the list, as @DerGolem said. plus insert this code to really check the value of mCursor.getCount()

Log.d("Count value", mCursor.getCount()+"");

Comment: You need to move the cusor to first row by mCursor.moveToFirst();

Comment: Sorry my fault.. I have edited the code... mistake in copy/paste...

Comment: If there is only 1 value that matches the condition you'll only get 1 result. It seems **obvious**... Or isn't it? `... WHERE Emirate = '"+s+"'"`: If there is only an Emirate called `Qatar`, you will only get a single Location row.

Comment: there hav around 7 rows matching it...

Comment: Your condition retrieves 1 record only. See my previous comment. **If you have more than one record where Emirate = 'Qatar', only the first one is retrieved**. Because the query is poorly written. You might want to use the **LIKE** operator, to get them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition retrieves **1 record** only.
If you have more than one record where Emirate = 'Qatar', only the first one is retrieved, because the **=** condition is satisfied.

You need to use the **LIKE** operator instead of **=**, to get them all.

Replace your query with:

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM Location WHERE Emirate LIKE '%" + s + "%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String query= "SELECT * FROM location where emirate='"+s+"'";
Cursor cursor1= db .rawQuery(query, null);


// Added by koutukto store offline record
while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {

    String data3 =cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("coloumname"));
    shoplist.add(data3 );

}
db.close();
```

Comment: for that you need to check your db file table location....containing more than one record for provided where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    String query= "SELECT * FROM location where emirate='"+s+"'";
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    int i= mCursor.getCount();

       if(mCursor.moveToFirst())

           do{

           shoplist.add(mCursor.getString(1));

           }while(mCursor.moveToNext());

        }

        mCursor.close();
        myDataBase.close();
```

You can check existing rows match to query using by `mCursor.moveToFirst()`. This method does two things for you; 
1. Move the cursor to the first row
2. Returns true if moving was succeed, means that if this method return true you have at least one row as result and you can continue your works.
And you can retrieve record in a while using by `mCursor.moveToNext()`.